# Way to execute a function on each getting of dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to define a dictionary to use as a template and upon getting of the value, have it execute a function

```
d = {'choice': random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> d.get('choice')
3
>>> d.get('choice')
1
>>> d.get('choice')
5
```

Ultimately, I'd like to have a list of these dictionary templates that I would loop over, and each time the dictionary is iterated upon, for certain fields (like `choice` above) I would like to have a random value out of the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new class that inherits from dict, then override `__getitem__`. For instance:

```py
import random

class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == "choice":
            return random.choice(super().__getitem__(key))
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)

d = MyDict(choice=[1,2,3,4,5],something_else=1)

print(d["choice"]) # outputs a random value from 1 to 5
print(d["something_else"]) # still outputs 1
```

This can be extended to use a second dict of templates used for custom behavior in `__getitem__` depending on the key.

Comment: As an addition, if you want to call a value whenever it's a function, you can use the `callable()` built-in; the body of the `__getitem__` would then be: `value = super().__getitem__(key); if callable(value): value = value(); return value`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up going with.  I override the `__getitem__` method and the `get` method to allow both `d['key']` and `d.get('key')` methods to work.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing you could do is just have the function be the value in the dictionary. So it would look like:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
d = {'choice': random.choice}
```

and then to actually get the number you can say `d['choice'](l)`. If you need more flexibility you can define your own lambda/wrapper functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the built-in `dict` class and specialize it by overriding its [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method to do what's needed.

In the example code below the function to call, arguments to pass it, and an id are all passed to the class initializer when an instance of the class is created — making it *very* generic because you can create separate instances that will call a different function (or passing the same one a different set of arguments or give it a different id).

Instance of the derived class can be otherwise be initialized and used like a normal dictionary.

```
class FuncDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, func_info=None, **kwargs):
        if not func_info or len(func_info) != 3:
            raise RuntimeError(
                    'A "func_info" keyword argument of three elements is required')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Initialize base class instance.
        self.func, self.func_args, self.func_id = func_info  # Save.

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return (self.func(self.func_args) if key == self.func_id
                else super().__getitem__(key))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import random

#    fd = FuncDict([('foobar', 42)], func_info=(random.choice, [1,2,3,4,5], 'choice'))
    fd = FuncDict(foobar=42, func_info=(random.choice, [1,2,3,4,5], 'choice'))

    print(fd['choice'])  # -> Some value from 1 to 5.
    print(fd['foobar']) # -> 42
```